# On wedge of H-spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've read that the wedge of two cyclic maps, $f\vee g$, does not need to be cyclic. Well, I understood the counter-example (see below) except by the fact that $S^1\vee S^1$ is not an H-space.

Where can I find a proof that $S^1\vee S^1$ is not an H-space?

**C.E.** Since $S^1$ is an H-space the identity map $1_{S^1}$ is cyclic. But $1_{S^1}\vee 1_{S^1}=1_{S^1\vee S^1}$ is not cyclic, for $S^1\vee S^1$ is not an H-space.

**edited:** I've found on Hatcher's book an exercise: *Show that if $(X,e)$ is an H-space then $\pi_1(X,e)$ is abelian*. Since we know that $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)=\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ is not abelian, the aim now is to solve the exercise.

Comment: Are you OK with the exercise? It's a problem everyone who wants to do homotopy theory (fundamental group) should attempt.

Comment: @M.B., thanks for attention. Tonight I'll think about the exercise. I believe that it's almost trivial. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the exercise cited above can be found on Hu's book *Homotopy theory*, Chapter III, section 11, Prop. 11.4.

**Proposition 11.4.** If $X$ is an H-space with $x_0$ as a homotopy unit, then the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is abelian.